# How to log GET/POSTS requests to a localfile?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to log the below data which is printing on console to local file. The below data is the GETS and POSTS of the apps of website and its printing on the console. I want to write it to a local log file. I am new to Django. Anyone Please guide me.

```
[08/Jan/2018 22:25:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5533
[08/Jan/2018 22:25:05] "GET /static/personal/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/Jan/2018 22:25:05] "GET /static/personal/img/logo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/Jan/2018 22:25:05] "GET /static/personal/img/img_avatar2.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/Jan/2018 22:25:08] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1909
[08/Jan/2018 22:25:11] "GET /contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1833
[08/Jan/2018 22:25:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5533
```

I am using the below logging file. Am i proceeding in the right way or not. Please Guide me Thank you in advance.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
       'console': {  # Log to stdout
           'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'django_debug.log'),
        }
    },
    'root': {  # For dev, show errors + some info in the console
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {  # debug logging of things that break requests
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is almost correct. You're just not logging requests with 2XX status code.

Change the logger name from [`django.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/#django-request) to [`django.server`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/#django-server) in order to log all HTTP requests (as opposed to just 4XX and 5XX).

Also from the documentation, the logger [`django`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/#django) is "The catch-all logger for messages in the django hierarchy", so use that to include all types of django messages.

Comment: what is the difference between django.request and django.server. And if i want to write each every log to file i need to change it from  django.request to django.server.

Comment: `django.request` logs 4XX and 5XX status codes only. `django.server` logs all status codes. click on the links in the answer they redirect you to the docs where this is explained in more detail. if you want to write all logs (not just django) define a logger with an empty string name and make sure you use `'propagate': True,` in all your defined loggers.